# How to use sed regex replace /*...*/ to ##...###?

Tags: linux, sed

Original input:

```
/*drwxr-xr-x  2 vt vt 1024 Dec  2 07:43 Music */
```

Expected output:

```
##drwxr-xr-x  2 vt vt 1024 Dec  2 07:43 Music ##
```

Comment: What is the real/final goal ? What are you trying to achieve ? Thanks to [**not** parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Is the `/*` always at the start of the line and `*/` always at the end? Would it be ok to replace these separately? Could you show more data?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sed -e 's;^/\*;##;' -e 's;\*/$;##;' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using back-references:

```bsh
sed 's!^/\*\(.*\)\*/$!##\1##!'
```

Using groups:

```bsh
sed 's!\(/\*\|\*/\)!##!g'
```